# Create new directory on repository in gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

I tried to create a new directory in a gitlab repository, but then it forked the whole repository and now it appears under my projects. I didn't fork, just created a new directory.

Why it did it automatically? 
Now I'm confused - am I work on the main repository? or on the one I fork? (not intentionally - it just forked once I tried to create a new directory on the main repo)

Also, if I'll create now a new branch  - where it will create it? In the new repo on my projects? or in the main repo?

And if I want to merge the changes to the master branch - where will it go? And how I make sure it will merge to the main repo and not the one under "my projects"?

Finally, how I can create a new directory in the main repo? (I have full access / rights on the main repo)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In [this](https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/create-directory/) gitlab document it is given that, you need to use shell to create directory. Follow the process given in that for creating directory.

As per fork is concerned, Go to settings in forked project and remove `fork relationship` and continue your work in main repo